# Is it possible to use a column from another join to create a condition in another join mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I will edit so it will not be classified as a duplicate.

I would like to use the XA.XA_REASON_CODE for a condition like statement to determine if I would use a condition or not.

If the XA.XA_REASON_CODE is = `EH` then I won't use `AND HOLDFLAG != 'R'`. Else use `AND HOLDFLAG != 'R'` in the condition for my join.

```
SELECT
 I.DATERELEASED,
 XA .XA_REASON_CODE,
FROM
    FEPC.EWHITEBOARD AS EWB
LEFT JOIN FEPC.EWHITEBOARD_XA XA ON EWB.EWHITEBOARD_ID = XA .EWHITEBOARD_ID
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT
        DATERELEASED
    FROM
        HOURLY_FT_WIP.CACHE_IRAC_HOLD_LOTS
    WHERE
        LOTNUM IN(
            'SAKZ3A024B',
            'JS61DA009G'
        )
if(XA.XA_REASON_CDOE = 'EH') THEN
    #nothing
else then
AND HOLDFLAG != 'R'
    )AS I ON I.LOTNUM = PRODUCTIONORDERID
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql IF Else Statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180218/mysql-if-else-statement)

Comment: rather ask a new question instead of changing your original question completely! this will make all the answers useless and confuse visitors who came here via e.g. google.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of logical `and` and `or` operators to achieve this behavior:

```
SELECT
    LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, SEX, AGE, CODE
FROM
    tblInfo
WHERE
    AGE > 20 AND 
    ((SEX = 'M' AND CODE = 'X') OR (SEX != 'M' AND CODE = 'Y'))
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is possible with `CASE`:

```
SELECT
        LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, SEX, AGE, CODE
    FROM
        tblInfo
    WHERE
        AGE > 20

AND CODE = CASE WHEN SEX = 'M' THEN 'X' ELSE 'Y' END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of bind-parameters.
Pass the value of the variable from your php code
and in the php code, simply determine the variable value using your if-else

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, SEX, AGE, CODE
FROM
  tblInfo
 WHERE
  AGE > 20
  AND CASE WHEN SEX = 'M' THEN CODE = 'X' ELSE CODE = 'Y' END
```